# how to make a salesforce1 tab available to a certain user

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-chatter

I am new to salesforce .
I have appended a tab which contains a visualforce page in my salesforce 1 app I want to make it availaible to some salesforce users.
How to do that?
how to add already existing users in my group.
thank you
Any guidance would be highly appreciated
Thanks